# VS2015 - NuGet Install-Package : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: powershell, nuget, visual-studio-2015

Something has gone catastrophically wrong with NuGet in my install of VS2015. Whenever I attempt to run Install-Package, I get the following error:

```
Install-Package : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package log4net
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.Install 
   PackageCommand
```

I can't for the life of me find any other information about this issue. I have restarted VS, restarted my PC, tried re-installing NuGet, but I feel like this is an underlying issue with powershell.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - SOLVED**

So, after a frustrating evening, I have finally solved the issue. I had to uninstall VS2015, re-install it, clear my `vssettings` file then delete the `NuGet.config` file.

Comment: Does this happen for all NuGet packages?

Comment: Yes - I've tried log4net, EntityFramework, JSON.NET and Bootstrap with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot guarantee that this will work but according to https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2239#issuecomment-193208925 the only thing you need to do is delete the nuget.config file.  Sorry if it doesn't work for you.